# Java regex pattern for a string

Tags: java, regex

I am new to `regex`. I am looking for regular expression which matches following pattern and extract the string,

```
 key1=test1
 key2="test1" // which will extract test1 stripping quotes
 key3=New test
 key4=New" "test // which will extract New" "test - as it is if the quotes come in between
```

I tried with `\\s*(\\S+)\\s*=\\s*(\\S+*+)` , but not sure how to include quotes if present. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without regex to avoid problems with nested quotes:

```
String extractValue(String input) {
  // check if '=' is present here...
  String[] pair = input.split("=", 2);
  String value = pair[1];
  if (value.startsWith("\"") && value.endsWith("\"")) {
      return value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Basically this is not without regex, because of the use of `split()`, but it's not using regex the way you were planning to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to just load it as a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), which will do exactly the parsing you're looking for. Otherwise, just [read each line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) and [split the string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) at the first "=".

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^([^=]+)=("([^"]*)"|([^"].*))$`, but the answer will show up in the third or fourth group depending on if the value was quoted or not so you'd need to check both and pull whichever one was not null.

Comment: what will you get for `key="va\"lue"`?

Comment: Okay but you didn't give the regex :)  Something like `/^([^=]*)=("(?:\\.|[^"\\]+)*"|[^"]*)$/` should handle escaped double quotes (although not escaped other characters)

Comment: Except of course it won't remove the backslash in the very example you gave in the comments above :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23783/discussion-between-jgm-and-jlordo)

Answer (score 0):

For Regex, if you want to include `"` in your regex, simply escape it using `\\"`. Whatever you are trying to achieve, test directly first at http://www.regexpal.com/